# Conversion a .nii image size

Tags: python

I have a .nii MRI file and the image size is 192,192.19. Is it possible to increase its size? If possible How can I convert this image into 256,256,32 in python.

I tried to resize this image into 256,256,32. I am expecting a solution in python.

Comment: what would you expect to change in the image, since you increased its size ? Zoom of the original ? white pixels added at the right / bottom / behind ? etc... Also, did you do any research beforehand ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize a nifti (nii.gz medical image) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674612/how-to-resize-a-nifti-nii-gz-medical-image-file)